# Error while trying to redirect 404 requests to home page in django

Tags: python, django

I would like to redirect all 404 errors to the index page of my django project. I am trying to do this by creating a view to handle all 404 requests and then adding the references to my urls.py.

This is what I have in my views.py. This is the classroom.py views in my views folder:

```
def view_404(request, exception=None):
    return redirect('/')
```

and my urls.py:

```
handler404 = 'classroom.classroom.view_404'
```

However I get the error message

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E008) The custom handler404 view 'classroom.classroom.view_404' could not be imported.
        HINT: Could not import 'classroom.classroom.view_404'. Parent module classroom.classroom does not exist.
```

Which I assume has more to do with how I am referencing the my views.py file.

Here is the structure of my project

```
multipleusers
-->django_project
---->templates
---->views
      classroom.py 
      students.py
      mentors.py
```

Comment: As per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#handler400 handler404 needs to point to the function. Can you please update your structure to show where the views.py file is with your view_404 function.  If it was in an app called "classroom" then the value would be ```classroom.views.view_404```

Comment: @SteveMapes my mistake. I have updated the question, the function is in classroom.py in the views folder

Comment: One last question. Is ```multipleusers``` your django project and ```django_project``` an app or do you have a central app called ```views``` and django_project``` is your project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Then it should be :

`<name_of_your_project>.<name_of_your_app>.views.classroom.view_404`

if `classroom` is effectively the name of your file in which your views are.